# Several questions, same problem, same user

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I have searched Meta for *several questions same problem same user*.
There were [(1) quite](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10601)
[(2) a few](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16978)
[(3) related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17040)
[(4) titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20403),
but these cover slightly different scenarios and do not seem to help here,
therefore I ask this question.

I have stumbled over
[(1) these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689303/)
[(2) three](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689460/)
[(3) posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689477/).
All three relate to the same problem by the same user.
All three have got suitable answers.
I have flagged one as a duplicate of (or contained within) another,
although I like the flagged one.
The third might be considered an abstract duplicate.

I do not like such spawning of essentially one question into three,
but the answers have already been given, and the only things possibly left
to do are of a librarian nature, it seems.

So, should there anything be done about such posts?
If so, what would it improve?

Comment: I did a bit of merging and closing. Flagging one of the posts for moderator attention solves any specific problem. Of course, we can (should) discuss the general procedures. The hive-mind can raise points of view missed by any single individual.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks. The meta-question is about whether such scenario, with answers already given, still calls for specific moderation. I suppose that mod attention is a scarce resource, so I would not want to invoke it unnecessarily.

Comment: Regular users can delete the violating (duplicate) thread in its entirety. That is a good action in many case. First close, then delete. Merging two versions of the same quetion is something only moderators can do. If there are good answers to the duplicate thread, then deletion will delete those as well. Merging will save them. But, merging does not always work very well in case of abstract duplicates. Also, deleting upvoted answers may cause an uproar. Most users have gotten used to good answers occasionally becoming collateral damage in other kinds of site maintenance though.